# Appending/concatenating two IEnumerable sequences

Tags: c#, ienumerable, unions

I have two sets of datarows. They are each IEnumerable. I want to append/concatenate these two lists into one list. I'm sure this is doable. I don't want to do a for loop and noticed that there is a Union method and a Join method on the two Lists. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the sets of datarows of the same type? Different types?

Comment: @Obed....they are of the same type

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Assuming your objects are of the same type, you can use either `Union` or `Concat`. Note that, like the SQL `UNION` keyword, the `Union` operation will ensure that duplicates are eliminated, whereas `Concat` (like `UNION ALL`) will simply add the second list to the end of the first.

```
IEnumerable<T> first = ...;
IEnumerable<T> second = ...;

IEnumerable<T> combined = first.Concat(second);
```

or

```
IEnumerable<T> combined = first.Union(second);
```

If they are of different types, then you'll have to `Select` them into something common. For example:

```
IEnumerable<TOne> first = ...;
IEnumerable<TTwo> second = ...;

IEnumerable<T> combined = first.Select(f => ConvertToT(f)).Concat(
                          second.Select(s => ConvertToT(s)));
```

Where `ConvertToT(TOne f)` and `ConvertToT(TTwo s)` represent an operation that somehow converts an instance of `TOne` (and `TTwo`, respectively) into an instance of `T`.

Comment: @Adam....I spoke too soon.  I have done the Union I am getting duplicate records.  Do Ineed to initialize a key property of some kind?

Comment: @MikeTWebb: `Union` has an overload that allows you to specify an `IEqualityComparer`.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered a similar situation where I need to concatenate multiple sequences.

Naturally searched for existing solutions on Google/StackOverflow, however did not find anything the did not evaluate the enumerable, e.g. convert to array then use `Array.Copy()` etc., so I wrote an extension and static utiltiy method called `ConcatMultiple`.

Hope this helps anyone that needs to do the same.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Concatenates multiple sequences
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the elements of the input sequences.</typeparam>
/// <param name="first">The first sequence to concatenate.</param>
/// <param name="source">The other sequences to concatenate.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ConcatMultiple<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, params IEnumerable<TSource>[] source)
{
    if (first == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("first");

    if (source.Any(x => (x == null)))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    return ConcatIterator<TSource>(source);
}

private static IEnumerable<TSource> ConcatIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, params IEnumerable<TSource>[] source)
{
    foreach (var iteratorVariable in first)
        yield return iteratorVariable;

    foreach (var enumerable in source)
    {
        foreach (var iteratorVariable in enumerable)
            yield return iteratorVariable;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Concatenates multiple sequences
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the elements of the input sequences.</typeparam>        
/// <param name="source">The sequences to concatenate.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ConcatMultiple<TSource>(params IEnumerable<TSource>[] source)
{
    if (source.Any(x => (x == null)))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    return ConcatIterator<TSource>(source);
}

private static IEnumerable<TSource> ConcatIterator<TSource>(params IEnumerable<TSource>[] source)
{
    foreach (var enumerable in source)
    {
        foreach (var iteratorVariable in enumerable)
            yield return iteratorVariable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join(v=vs.100).aspx) method is like a SQL join, where the list are cross referenced based upon a condition, it isn't a string concatenation or Adding to a list.  The [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb341731(v=vs.100).aspx) method does do what you want, as does the [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx) method, but both are LAZY evaluations, and have the requirement the parameters be non-null. They return either a ConcatIterator or a UnionIterator, and [if called repeatedly this could cause problems](http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/how-enumerableconcat-brought-down-a-production-server.html). Eager evaluation results in different behavior, if that is what you want, then an extension method like the below could be used.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> myEagerConcat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first,
                                                   IEnumerable<T> second)
{
    return (first ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()).Concat(
           (second ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>())).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Delayed invocation of the second and subsequent enumerables**

I usually use Linq `IEnumerable<T>.Concat()` but today I needed to be 100% sure that the second enumeration was not enumerated until the first one has been processed until the end. (e.g. two db queries that I didn't want to run simultaneously). So the following function made the trick to delay the enumerations.

```
    IEnumerable<T> DelayedConcat<T>(params Func<IEnumerable<T>>[] enumerableList)
    {
        foreach(var enumerable in enumerableList)
        {
            foreach (var item in enumerable())
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    return DelayedConcat(
                () => GetEnumerable1(),
                () => GetEnumerable2(),
 // and so on.. () => GetEnumerable3(),
                );
```

In this example GetEnumerable2 function invocation will be delayed until GetEnumerable1 has been enumerated till the end.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L806

Pretty much equal to the reference implementation

Comment: Incorrect @TJHeuvel . That one receives two enumerations, but mine receives two `Func<IEnumerable<T>>` and ensures you don't create the 2nd enumerable until the first one has been depleted.