# Compiling a lambda expression with multiple input parameters on two IEnumerables

Tags: c#, .net, join, ienumerable, expression

I have two `IEnumerables` called `IEnumerable<TBL_Country>` and `IEnumberable<TBL_City>` which their table definitions came from my ORM and I would like to execute the following Expression Function in order to join the IEnumerables but it's not possible. 
Any Idea!

```
IEnumerable<TBL_COUNTRY> country = new IEnumerable<TBL_Country>();
IEnumerable<TBL_COUNTRY> city = new IEnumerable<TBL_CITY>();
Expression<Func<TBL_COUNTRY,TBL_CITY,bool>> func =
    (p,q) => p.fk_city_id = q.pk_city_id & p.name = "SomeName";
```

Comment: they arent both called IEnumerable, IEnumerable is their type. one is called country, the other city.

Comment: At the very least, your lambda result should be `p.fk_city_id == q.pk_city_id && p.name == "SomeName"` - double `=` for logical equality check, double `&` (usually) for logical AND.

Comment: Quite apart from any other errors, you're performing assignment (`=`) rather than equality comparison (`==`) in your expression. The compiler is probably telling you that.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961910/joining-or-appending-two-ienumerable-sequences?rq=1 ? Might be a more elegant way of fixing your problem

Comment: If you want to join two enumerables check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723985/linq-join-2-listts You should be able to rework that answer into a func that joins your lists.

Comment: ...and you can't create an instance of IEnumerable (i.e. new IEnumerable<Blah>()). It's an interface, hence the I prefix.